# mongoose (mongodb) Alias _id field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible with mongoose use a different name, in my case uppercase 'ID', as an alias for the schema _id field?
Would I need to add a virtual or is there another way of setting this up?

Any help gratefully received thanks.

Comment: This helps too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239358/adding-virtual-variables-to-a-mongoose-schema

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You would use a [virtual attribute](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) for that.  As in:

```
yourSchema.virtual('ID').get(function() { return this._id; });
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to specify `alias` in the schema:

```
let s = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, alias: "ID" }
});
```

This automatically creates both getter and setter, so it is possible to use `ID` everywhere instead of `_id`.

[Mongoose documentation on aliases](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Based on `v5.11.9` mongoose documentation looks like mongoose assigns each of your [schemas an id virtual getter by default](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) which returns the document's `_id` field