# Adding 'virtual' variables to a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following document schema:

```
var pageSchema = new Schema({
      name: String
    , desc: String
    , url: String
})
```

Now, in my application I would like to also have the html source of the page inside the object, but I do not want to store it in the db.

Should I create a "local" enhanced object which has a reference to the db document?

```
function Page (docModel, html) {
    this._docModel = docModel
    this._html = html
}
```

Is there a way to use the document model directly by adding a "virtual" field?

Comment: Why do you want to have it in the object but not store it?

Comment: Because I do not need it to be persistent: if I reboot my server and reload the objects from database, that html would need to be updated too (it comes from an external process). I could store it, but it would be wasted space.

Since in Mongoose there are virtual methods, it would have been nice to also have virtual variables..

Comment: You can simply set [damn enter] a property on the object like `document.prop = html`. I don't think that method or virtuals will actually let you fetch "local" data if you fetch the object from the db again though, even if not restarting.

Comment: Oh, right. I can simply add a new property. What confused me was that if I do `page.newProperty = "something"; console.log(page)` it does not show the `newProperty` in the output.. but if I do `console.log(page.newProperty)` I see the value :|

Comment: Don't do this. Check my answer, virtuals are supported by mongoose.

Answer (score 37):

This is perfectly possible in mongoose.
Check this example, taken from their documentation:

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: String,
    last: String
  }
});

personSchema.virtual('name.full').get(function () {
  return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});
console.log('%s is insane', bad.name.full); // Walter White is insane
```

In the above example, the property would not have a setter. To have a setter for this virtual, do this:

```
personSchema.virtual('name.full').get(function () {
  return this.name.full;
}).set(function(name) {
  var split = name.split(' ');
  this.name.first = split[0];
  this.name.last = split[1];
});
```

[Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)

Comment: Yes but they are not adding new fields.. They are using existing ones.

Comment: And what's the problem? You can use setters also.

Comment: oh, I see. you mean I should `this.newfield =` inside the virtual `set`.

Comment: Not sure it makes any sense though :l

Comment: I had to activate virtuals for the "toObject" and "toJSON" in schema options. Otherwise it did not work for me . Here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

Answer (score 16):

Document properties that start with `__` are not persisted to the db, so you could create a virtual property and have the getter and setter use `this.__html`

```
pageSchema.virtual('html').get(function () {
  return this.__html;
}).set(function (html) {
  this.__html = html;
});
```

but this is a bit of a hack with a caveat: this functionality is not documented so there is no list of internal properties that start with `__`  so there is a possibility, albeit unlikely, that in the future the internal implementation could start using a var called `__html`

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2642

Answer (score 13):

I have not actually tested this but the idea seems worthy:

```
//model
var pageSchema = new Schema({
      name: String
    , desc: String
    , url: String
})

pageSchema.virtual('html')
  .get(function(){
    var url = this.url

    function get(url) {
      return new (require('httpclient').HttpClient)({
        method: 'GET',
          url: url
        }).finish().body.read().decodeToString();
    }

    return get(url);
  });


  //controller
  var page = new Page({
    name: "Google"
    , desc: "Search engine"
    , url: "http://google.com"
  });

  var html = page.html;
```

Basically set a virtual attribute called `html` which requests the body for the `url` attribute and returns it.

Be sure to enable outputting of virtual attributes for toJSON if you are using express and `res.send(page)`.

```
pageSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**In 2020**

You can set a virtual object by adding below objects fields in model.

```
toJSON: { virtuals: true },
toObject: { virtuals: true }
```

above example and below example are equivalent, but above is short and simple.

```
itemSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

#### Here is the Example

**Model**

```
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Please provide item image']
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    size: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please provide item price']
    },
    shipping: {
        type: Number
    },
    discount: {
        type: Number
    },
    details: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
}, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
});
```

**Set VirtualSchema**

```
itemsSchema.virtual('totalPrice').get(function() {
    const sub_total = this.price + this.shipping;
    return (sub_total - ( ( sub_total / 100 ) * this.discount )).toFixed(2)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works on my end:

```js
const studentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String
    }
});

// Add virtual variables here"
studentSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function () {
    return `${this.name.firstName} ${this.name.lastName}`
});
```