# MongoDB, Mongoose - what is the best way for adding non-persistent data field to the schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Mongoose schema and I need to add a non-persistent field to it. The point of this field is to store some status, related to persistent data fields, but without need to store it to the database. I see that some Mongoose alternatives provide such a feature e.g. https://github.com/simpleviewinc/mongolayer#modeladdfieldargs, however I am not able to find similar one inside Mongoose.

Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose you have the concept of virtual fields. See doc (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

See also related topic at [Adding 'virtual' variables to a mongoose schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239358/adding-virtual-variables-to-a-mongoose-schema)

Comment: Thank you. You helped me in a Monday morning.