# Adding new pair to Javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose

In a `Node.js` App, i have an object named `user` with this content:

```
{
   name:'john',
   family:'jackson'
}
```

i want to add a new pair dynamically like this:

```
user["city"] =  "new york";
```

but its not work! when i print it like this:

```
console.log(user);
```

i see the same content as above:

```
{
   name:'john',
   family:'jackson'
}
```

but when i print this:

```
console.log(user.city);
```

it prints this:

```
new york
```

but why?? i send this result to browser and its without `city` key/value still!

**Update:**

in a plain javascript all things i explained works. my problem is when i work with node js and after fetching some data from database with Mongoose like this:

```
Users.find({followings:{$elemMatch:{$in:[userID]}}}).exec(function(err, users){
     users[0]["city"] =  "new york"; // this doesn't work. this adds city to users but doesnt show in console.log(users[0])
});
```

but why? users is a regular Javascript object. why i get this behavior?

Comment: what is `user` here? is it a variable referring to that object?

Comment: yes it is that object

Comment: it works in plain old javascript, at least in my FF console. I don't know node.js enough to help you further

Comment: Could you show us your full code? It's hard to tell why your problem is occurring here. It looks like it should work the way it is to me.

Comment: @towerofnix: its whole code. im testing it. in the Node side i can access to city value but when i send it to browser, there is no any city

Comment: I haven't used node enough to quite figure out how to solve your problem with just the information you've given. Please show us your whole file..

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMy6eIp3WpAUqWGFzy3K2jyAm1esEik-xE

Comment: "but when i send it to browser" — When do you do that? There's no code there which would send it anywhere other than the console.

Comment: @Quentin:  i updated my question

Comment: @rajuGT:  i updated my question

Comment: Mongoose objects are not plain objects, they're instances of the model class.

Comment: @DaveNewton: but i always treat with them like regular object and it works. now what i have to do? i have to convert it? how?

Comment: @Fcoder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239358/adding-virtual-variables-to-a-mongoose-schema etc. IIRC it's also in the Mongoose docs. It'd probably be worth your while to spend some time understanding what Mongoose is, how it works, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i findout whats the problem. When i do a mongoose query, result is not a plain javascript object. with using lean() i can tell to Mongoose that skip creating regular Mongoose Model. then i changed this:

```
Users.find({followings:{$elemMatch:{$in:[userID]}}}).exec(function(err, users){
     users[0]["city"] =  "new york"; // this doesn't work. this adds city to users but doesnt show in console.log(users[0])
});
```

to this:

```
Users.find({followings:{$elemMatch:{$in:[userID]}}}).lean().exec(function(err, users){
     users[0]["city"] =  "new york"; //works now!
});
```

And it works!

Comment: `lean()` is *an* option, but it removes all Mongoose-ness from the resulting object. Personally I think you'd be better off using a virtual property, but it depends entirely on your needs; this is fine for shuffling data off to the view, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var user = {'name':'John'};
user["city"] = "New York";
console.log(user);
```

Can you try this simple code and see what node logs?
It should spit out this:

```
Object {name: "John", city: "New York"}
```

**Explaination:**

In our example we are setting an Object with a property `name` and a value of `John`
The second line simply adds an extra property `city` and a value of `New York`
The third line logs the Object with the new property

Comment: Great. Now I get it! :) :P

Comment: How is this any different from what the OP is specifically saying doesn't work?